# How do I reduce overhead of passing a matrix to a function?

Tags: c++, function, memory

I am performing statistics on 2 rather large (2+ GB each) 3D arrays and I perform that computation inside a function:

```
double stats(vector< vector< vector< double > > > A, vector< vector< vector< double > > > B);
```

I believe that a large amount of the time taken by the program is simply passing `A` and `B` to my function, rather than actually performing the statistics *inside* the function.

Does this seem reasonable? Is there substantial overhead from passing these `vector`s to a function? If so, what is the best way to account for this? I know that I could simply put all of these functions inside a `class` and then refer to the arrays in terms of a class member, but I was hoping to keep these functions class agnostic if possible.

Comment: out of scope....vector< vector< vector< double > > >  is considered a bad practice.. I have heard that once...

Comment: Besides passing by references, consider writing your own matrix class ( or using an existing one ) such that you don't have so much deference.  With a `vector<vector<vector<...>>>`, only 1D rows are guaranteed to use contiguous memory.  You probably want some `double[]` array that contains all the data and then use some smart maths to do 3D indexing on that 1D array.  If your array has a dynamic size, it will begin to get difficult to get it right and efficient, so forget my comment.

Comment: Agreed - I'm working on a `matrix` class, but class nuances and memory management are still a struggle for me. I'm using `vector` to do automated cleanup and throw it on hundreds of cores and then worry about fine tuning later ;)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, well, yeah, more often than not, if someone has a data structure THAT complex, they need to seriously rethink their program.

Comment: Laurbert515, it's a balance. You should not leave the major thinking about performance until after you write the code, because the rewrite is MUCH harder than the initial write in those cases. Come up with a basic structure that SHOULD be efficient, take a few easy-to-change shortcuts to speed up the initial building, and then fine tune from there. Don't use a complex structure like this if you can forsee problems with it, otherwise you're building a skyscraper on a sandbar, and THEN pouring a new foundation under it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the arrays by reference. Note the ampersands, &:

```
double stats(vector< vector< vector< double > > > & A, vector< vector< vector< double > > > & B);
```

Passing by value as you are will cause the vectors to be copied, incurring performance and memory overhead.

If you don't need to modify the vectors within `stats`, also consider using a `const` reference:

```
double stats(vector< vector< vector< double > > > const& A, vector< vector< vector< double > > > const& B);
```

Comment: Yep, thought of that immediately after posting! Now added to the answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that while `vector< vector< vector< double > > > const& A` is perfectly fine, most people prefer to use `const vector< vector< vector< double > > >& A` - In case other people look at your code.

Comment: Right on, @atkins! That said, a quick note to any other readers...if your data structure is this complex, passing by value or reference is the least of your worries. Rethink your design.